# Route53 Private hosted zone certificate

Tags: amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have created a private hosted zone on AWS Route 53. I want to know what is the best way to create certificates for an internal load balancer that has a record entry in the private hosted zone.
Does AWS provide a solution?

Comment: Please accept the answer if you're happy with it. Thanks!

Comment: Done, thank you @kixorz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use brand new `AWS Certificate Manager`.

[See official AWS Certificate Manager documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html)

Also please keep in mind you have to manually renew your certificate.

Comment: Thanks @kixorz, is it the same process to follow as for requesting certs for any other public domain?

Comment: @mailtobash the process is the same.  Certificates not accessible on the Internet have to be manually renewed each year because ACM can't access your private services to verify that the certs are still in use.